# css tabs with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi I am trying to create tabs with CSS and Jquery but I dont know why I am not getting the right content when the appropriate tab is selected. thanks for ur time

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
<head>
<title>Follow me!</title>
<style type="text/css">
    ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px; /*--Subtract 1px from the height of the unordered list--*/
    line-height: 31px; /*--Vertically aligns the text within the tab--*/
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px; /*--Pull the list item down 1px--*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff; /*--Gives the bevel look with a 1px white border inside the list item--*/
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { /*--Makes sure that the active tab does not listen to the hover properties--*/
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /*--Makes the active tab look like it's connected with its content--*/
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left; width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#link1" class="tab_content">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link2" class="tab_content">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link3" class="tab_content">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="tab_content">
            <div id="link1">
                <p>Link1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link2">
                <p>Link2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link3">
                <p>Link3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
$(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
```

makes me think that you expect `.tab_content` to reference each content `<div>`. Currently it doesn't.

I'd remove the `"tab_content"` class from the parent of the content sections, and place it on each individual section.

```
<div>
    <div class="tab_content" id="link1">  
        <p>Link1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content" id="link2"> 
        <p>Link2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab_content" id="link3">  
        <p>Link3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** And remove the `tab_content` class from the links.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Link4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="">Link5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Patrick. I tried that but still doesnt work.

Comment: @user - Sorry, didn't notice you were using the same `tab_content` class on the links. I'd remove that class from those links. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/azelo3/2

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
<head>
<title>Follow me!</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px; /*--Set height of tabs--*/
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.tabs li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 31px; /*--Subtract 1px from the height of the unordered list--*/
    line-height: 31px; /*--Vertically aligns the text within the tab--*/
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: none;
    margin-bottom: -1px; /*--Pull the list item down 1px--*/
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
ul.tabs li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border: 1px solid #fff; /*--Gives the bevel look with a 1px white border inside the list item--*/
    outline: none;
}
ul.tabs li a:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}
html ul.tabs li.active, html ul.tabs li.active a:hover  { /*--Makes sure that the active tab does not listen to the hover properties--*/
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff; /*--Makes the active tab look like it's connected with its content--*/
}
.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-top: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left; width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
}
.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.tab_content div {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $("ul.tabs li:first-child a").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content #link1").css("display", "block"); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li a").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li a").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(".tab_content div").css("display","none");

        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab


        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
</script>


</head>
<body>

            <ul class="tabs">
                <li><a href="#link1" class="tab_content">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link2" class="tab_content">Link2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#link3" class="tab_content">Link3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="">Link5</a></li>
            </ul>
        <div class="tab_content">
            <div id="link1">
                <p>Link1</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link2">
                <p>Link2</p>
            </div>
            <div id="link3">
                <p>Link3</p>
            </div>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```